# JavaFX Filling up GridPane dynamically faster using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-threads

I'm loading data from my DB and dynamically creating buttons inside GridPane! But with a lot of data it takes too long to see the buttons!
I am using Threads to load data from the DB, but it seems that creating each button and filling up the GridPane takes too long!

**I tried creating hard coded data and filling the GridPane with them just for testing but again it takes too long, so with this I conclude that the problem that makes the buttons take too long to show is filling up the GridPane, not loading data from the DB!

Is there any way how to fill the GridPane faster?
I am using 2 for loops, one for the rows and the other for columns, so the complexity is (n-square)!

Can I optimize it?

Here are my functions for creating and filling up the GridPane:

```
public void initialize() throws Exception {
    initializedProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    productsOnReceipt = new ArrayList<>();
    rows = new VBox();
    grandPrice = 0;

    //Initializing DatabaseConnections and accessors for each sections
    ProductDao burgerAccessor = new ProductDaoImpl();
    ProductDao burgerMenuAccessor = new ProductDaoImpl();
    ProductDao drinksAccessor = new ProductDaoImpl();

    Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });

    initSections(burgers_section, 2, "PICI", exec, burgerAccessor);
    initSections(burgersMenu_section, 2, "TOPLI JADENJA", exec, burgerMenuAccessor);
    initSections(drinks_section, 1, "BEZALKOHOLNI PIJALOCI", exec, drinksAccessor);
}
```

Initializing sections for products:

```
private void initSections(ScrollPane section, int rows, String category, Executor executor, ProductDao products) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    grid.setHgap(20);
    grid.setVgap(-7);
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    initProducts(grid, rows, category, executor, products);
    section.setContent(grid);
}
```

Initializing products for each section:

```
private void initProducts(GridPane grid, int rows, String category, Executor executor, ProductDao accessor) {
    Task<Products> productsResultTask = new Task<Products>() {
        @Override
        protected Products call() throws Exception {
            return accessor.getByCategory(category);
        }
    };

    productsResultTask.setOnFailed(e -> productsResultTask.getException().printStackTrace());

    productsResultTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        if (productsResultTask.getValue() != null) {
            ArrayList<Product> products = productsResultTask.getValue().getProducts();
            int productCounter = 0;
            if (rows == 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < products.size(); j++) {
                    initializeButton(category, products.get(productCounter), grid, 0, j);
                    initializedProducts.add(products.get(productCounter));
                    productCounter++;
                }
            } else {
                if (isEven(products.size())) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < products.size() / 2; j++) {
                            initializeButton(category, products.get(productCounter), grid, i, j);
                            initializedProducts.add(products.get(productCounter));
                            productCounter++;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < (products.size()-1) / 2; j++) {
                            initializeButton(category, products.get(productCounter), grid, i, j);
                            initializedProducts.add(products.get(productCounter));
                            productCounter++;
                        }
                    }
                    initializeButton(category, products.get(productCounter), grid, 0, ((products.size() - 1) / 2));
                    initializedProducts.add(products.get(productCounter));
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't fetch products from DB!");
        }
    });
    executor.execute(productsResultTask);
}
```

**I don't think there is a problem with the below initializeButton() function, but just in case you can see how the work flows!

Initializing each button for each product:

```
private void initializeButton(String category, Product product, GridPane grid, int i, int j) {
        Label bName = new Label(product.getName());
        bName.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16;");
        bName.setPrefWidth(130);
        bName.setWrapText(true);
        bName.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: center;");
        bName.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button button = new Button();
        button.setPrefHeight(110);
        button.setPrefWidth(130);

        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/burgerm.png").toExternalForm()),
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(120, 100, false, false, false, false));
        Background background = new Background(backgroundImage);
        button.setBackground(background);
        button.setStyle("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), 10, 0, 0, 0);");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (category.equals("TOPLI JADENJA")) {
                askForDrink(product);
            } else {
                addToReceipt(product);
            }

        });

        VBox item = new VBox();
        item.getChildren().addAll(button, bName);
        item.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        item.setSpacing(-8);
        item.setPrefWidth(110);
        grid.add(item, j, i);
    }
```

Comment: *"I am using 2 for loops, one for the rows and the other for columns, so the complexity is (n-square)!"* Statements like this are misleading. You do not specify, what `n` is, but most likely you're wrong: the number of products seems to be independent from `rows` resulting in complexity `rows * products.size()`. For a large number of products it would be better to use a virtualizing control. [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) may be an option. Also there's no need to do 2 seperate nested for loops: integer division results are rounded towards 0.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say for the complexity `rows * products.size()` my mistake here! 
I have no idea about virtualizing control, I'll give it a try! 

For the 2 seperated nested for loops it's not because of dividing an odd number, but because if the number of products is odd I do the same thing as for even number of products (Filling the 2 rows with products) and at the end add one more product on the first row of the last column!

Maybe I can refactor this by using a function for my nested for loops so I don't duplicate the same code!

But again, my main problem is the performance!

Answer (score -3):

You have got a few potential performance killers in there.

Why do you load the backgroundImage over and over again. You could load it just once outside of the loops and reuse it.

Try to reduce your code to the absolute minimum. Plain buttons without any CSS and other decorations and then compare the performance.

Could you provide a few numbers. What is slow for you?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you need to ask the OP to clarify something, please post it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: About the background image: Each product(Button) will have it's own image later but in my code I'm just testing with the same image, is there any better way to load those images faster if you think that's my problem?

It was the same without CSS, for slow is waiting 4 seconds just to load all the products and show them on the screen ;/

Thank you!

Comment: @mipa You helped me figure it out what is slowing down my app! I removed the background image and It optimized from 4sec to just about 1sec! 
But is there a faster way to load images, because I want each button to have it's own image! ?